# In Radius , does the authentication port and the accounting port being consecutive number an industry standard?

Tags: radius, freeradius, radius-protocol

During the configuration of RADIUS client, does the authentication port and the accounting port have to be consecutive port numbers? I know that you can give different port numbers in /etc/services but I wanted to know whether it was the industry standard  or not?

Answer (score 0):

1812/1813 are the official IANA port numbers assigned to RADIUS Authentication and Accounting.

If you choose ports in the ephemeral range, there's no requirement for them to be consecutive.

If you use RADSEC only one port is used (TCP/2083)